# JAVA comparator for UTF8 letters

Tags: java, comparator

I've checked several posts about comparators, but I stuck at one point.

Comparator I' am using:

```
@Override
    public int compare(BaseFolder arg0, BaseFolder arg1) {
        try {
            Object value1 = arg0.getName();
            Object value2 = arg1.getName();

            Collator lithuanianCollator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("lt_LT"));
            lithuanianCollator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
            int value = lithuanianCollator.compare(value1.toString(), value2.toString());

            return SortOrder.ASCENDING.equals(sortOrder) ? value : -1 * value;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
```

It does sort, but it doesn't work properly on Lithuanian letters, and I got no idea why.

EDIT: seems sorting depends on string length, for some reason.

For example.

[image]

EDIT:

```
public class BaseFolder {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String lastModifiedBy;
    private String lastModificationDate;
    private String createdBy;
    private String creationDate;
    private String parentId;

    public BaseFolder() {
    }
    public BaseFolder(CmisObject obj) {
        this.id = obj.getId();
        this.name = obj.getName();
        this.description = obj.getDescription();
        this.lastModificationDate = DateFormatUtils.format(obj.getLastModificationDate().getTime(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
        this.lastModifiedBy = obj.getLastModifiedBy();
        this.createdBy = obj.getCreatedBy();
        this.creationDate = DateFormatUtils.format(obj.getCreationDate().getTime(), "yyyy-MM-dd");


    }
    public BaseFolder(String id, String name, String description, String parentId) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put(PropertyIds.PARENT_ID, "cmis:parentId");
        properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:folder");
        properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, getName());
        properties.put(PropertyIds.DESCRIPTION, getDescription());
        return properties;
    }
```

Using java 8, Primefaces, JSF

Comment: I guess since `value1` and `value2` are of type Object toString() returns the String representation of the objects. Could you share the code of `BaseFolder`?

Comment: What's wrong with the sorting ?

Comment: Editied:  basefolder class.

And about sorting. 
first should come     a, then ą ,   or i comes before į

Comment: Try changing `Object value1 = arg0.getName();` to `String value1 = arg0.getName();` and `Object value2 = arg1.getName();` to `String value2 = arg1.getName();`

Comment: Sadly, no, no difference, still generates same output.

Comment: I thought `ą` is only in Polish.

Comment: This happens even with ASCII letters.  An English Collator sorts `"a", "aaaaa", "A", "AAAAA"` the same way as described in the question (and the comments below), even when the strength is Collator.IDENTICAL, which seems incorrect to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this code to order

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] words = {"ą", "a", "į", "i", "ąąąąą", "aaaaa"};

    Collator en_USCollator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("en","US"));
    Collator lt_LTCollator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("lt","LT"));

    sortStrings(en_USCollator, words);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
    sortStrings(lt_LTCollator, words);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
}

public static void sortStrings(Collator collator, String[] words) {
    String tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < words.length; j++) { 
            if (collator.compare(words[i], words[j]) > 0) {
                tmp = words[i];
                words[i] = words[j];
                words[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

This is the output

```
[a, ą, aaaaa, ąąąąą, i, į]
[a, ą, aaaaa, ąąąąą, i, į]
```

**UPDATE**

You can use RuleBasedCollator

```
    String simple = "< a< ą< i< į";
    RuleBasedCollator lt_LTCollator = new RuleBasedCollator(simple);
```

This is the output

```
[a, aaaaa, ą, ąąąąą, i, į]
```

Here there is more information
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html

Comment: same as here, it should be

[a, aaaaa, ą, ąąąąą, i, į ]

edit:
even 
[aaaaa, a, ąąąąą, ą, į, i ]

would be ok for now, if that makes any difference

Comment: Let me know if it helped you.

Comment: **winner winner chicken dinner** ! ! !   ;)


works as it should,  Thank you Sir, helped me alot !